# Emacs and Unix Screen

Tags: unix, emacs, terminal, gnu-screen

I'm in Screen and have one window set to emacs. When I leave that window and maneuver to a different one, say screen two or three, the text in the original emacs window gets discombobulated. The line wraps are confused and I have to minimize and maximize the terminal app before the text is usable again.

This has only been a problem in emacs. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I have no such trouble switching between an emacs document, a tail of /var/log/system.log and a top window in screen.

I've exported my current terminal settings and they are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BackgroundAlphaInactive</key>
    <real>0.74631954479768781</real>
    <key>BackgroundBlur</key>
    <real>0.0</real>
    <key>BackgroundBlurInactive</key>
    <real>0.0</real>
    <key>BackgroundColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0cw
    IDAuOTgAEAOAAtIQERITWiRjbGFzc25hbWVYJGNsYXNzZXNXTlNDb2xvcqISFFhOU09i
    amVjdF8QD05TS2V5ZWRBcmNoaXZlctEXGFRyb290gAEIERojLTI3O0FIUF1kbG5wdYCJ
    kZSdr7K3AAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAGQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALk=
    </data>
    <key>BackgroundSettingsForInactiveWindows</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CursorBlink</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CursorColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0sw
    LjMwMjQxOTM2ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRY
    TlNPYmplY3RfEA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZHBy
    dHmEjZWYobO2uwAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC9
    </data>
    <key>Font</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGGBlYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKQHCBESVSRudWxs1AkKCwwNDg8QVk5TU2l6ZVhOU2ZGbGFnc1ZOU05hbWVWJGNs
    YXNzI0AsAAAAAAAAEBCAAoADVk1vbmFjb9ITFBUWWiRjbGFzc25hbWVYJGNsYXNzZXNW
    TlNGb250ohUXWE5TT2JqZWN0XxAPTlNLZXllZEFyY2hpdmVy0RobVHJvb3SAAQgRGiMt
    Mjc8QktSW2JpcnR2eH+Ej5ifoqu9wMUAAAAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAxw==
    </data>
    <key>FontAntialias</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FontWidthSpacing</key>
    <real>0.99596774193548387</real>
    <key>Linewrap</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProfileCurrentVersion</key>
    <real>2.02</real>
    <key>SelectionColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OVU5TUkdCXE5TQ29sb3JTcGFjZVYkY2xhc3NGMCAw
    IDEAEAKAAtIQERITWiRjbGFzc25hbWVYJGNsYXNzZXNXTlNDb2xvcqISFFhOU09iamVj
    dF8QD05TS2V5ZWRBcmNoaXZlctEXGFRyb290gAEIERojLTI3O0FITltiaWttcn2GjpGa
    rK+0AAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAGQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALY=
    </data>
    <key>ShowShellCommandInTitle</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ShowWindowSettingsNameInTitle</key>
    <false/>
    <key>TerminalType</key>
    <string>vt102</string>
    <key>TextBoldColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OVU5TUkdCXE5TQ29sb3JTcGFjZVYkY2xhc3NPEB0w
    Ljk4MTE0OTkwNDUgMSAwLjA0ODk0MDY0OTEyABABgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRj
    bGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3RfEA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9v
    dIABCBEaIy0yNztBSE5bYoKEhouWn6eqs8XIzQAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAADP
    </data>
    <key>TextColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OVU5TUkdCXE5TQ29sb3JTcGFjZVYkY2xhc3NPECgw
    LjgyNDA5NTkzMjkgMC44Mzk5Mjg2Njg1IDAuMDQxMTA2NjU0MjUAEAGAAtIQERITWiRj
    bGFzc25hbWVYJGNsYXNzZXNXTlNDb2xvcqISFFhOU09iamVjdF8QD05TS2V5ZWRBcmNo
    aXZlctEXGFRyb290gAEIERojLTI3O0FITltijY+RlqGqsrW+0NPYAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAA
    AAAAGQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANo=
    </data>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Pro</string>
    <key>shellExitAction</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>type</key>
    <string>Window Settings</string>
    <key>warnOnShellCloseAction</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I trust you haven't used the scroll bar in the other screens...

One thing you might try is setting your $TERM variable to vt102; Mine was set to 'screen'.   If you let me know if there's a specific mode you're using, or a kind of file that I could edit to duplicate the problem, I'll look further for you...